# Persisting Homebrew's ssh-agent

Tags: terminal, homebrew, ssh

I've installed OpenSSH from Homebrew, because I need a newer version to support hardware keys (Big Sur comes with 8.1; 8.2+ is needed).

However, my system insists on persisting the default `ssh-agent` stored in `/usr/bin` rather than the one in `/opt/homebrew/bin/ssh-agent`. I can manually change over to the Homebrew agent with `eval (ssh-agent -c)`, but this isn't persisted across new terminal sessions.

In case it matters, I'm using iTerm and fish shell. I don't simply want to put `eval (ssh-agent -c)` into my fish config, because then I would still have to run `ssh-add -K` every time I open a new terminal window with the intention of using SSH. With the bundled agent, I only have to run `ssh-add` once, and it persists across sessions.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have "Remote Login" enabled under System Preferences » Sharing? If yes, try disabling that. I'm not sure if that will solve the problem, but it turns on `sshd`, so I'm guessing that it _might_. Worth a shot at least, if you haven't tried it already.

Comment: @TJLuoma No, Remote Login is not enabled. I don't have any sharing items enabled, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using bash here (but the procedure must be easy to port to fish, zsh or other shell)

Run `cat ~/.ssh/<yourkey>.pub` which outputs something like this

```
ssh-<krypto gibberish> <some string>
```

Copy a bit of the `<some string>` part and add below:

```
KEYS=$(ssh-add -L)
if [[ "$KEYS" != *"<some string>"* ]]
then
    ssh-add -K .ssh/<yourkey> [optional other keys] >/dev/null
fi
```

The next time you open a terminal it will check if your key is loaded, and if not, load it.

I use the above solution since I have multiple keys for work etc, and that screws up the built-in ssh-agent auto-load as well.

Comment: The problem here is every single terminal window I open, it reverts to the in-built version of ssh-agent, which does not support security keys. Every window I open asks for my key's PIN, then fails to add the key because `ssh-add` is the correct version but `ssh-agent` is not.

Comment: Add the path to you ssh-add and see if that makes a difference then?

Comment: It's in the path. Oddly, it just ... started working the other day. No idea how or why. I didn't even reboot the system.